# How to find an approximate equation from a given equation using Mathematica?

Tags: approximation, mathematica-online

I am interested in finding an approximate equation based on a given equation using Mathematica. Specifically, I am working with the quantum illumination transmitter's quantum Chernoff bound (Bhattacharyya bound), where the expression for the probability of error is provided as follows:

$\begin{aligned} \operatorname{Pr}(e)_{C S} & \leq \frac{1}{2} e^{-M k N_S\left(\sqrt{N_B+1}-\sqrt{N_B}\right)^2}  \hspace{45pt} (1)\\ & \approx \frac{1}{2} e^{-\frac{M k N_S}{4 N_B}}, \text { when } N_B \gg 1\hspace{37pt}(2)\end{aligned}$

The equation (2) is an approximation of equation (1) when the condition $N_B \gg 1$ holds. The approximation can be derived theoretically by performing a binomial expansion and applying the following simplification:

$\begin{aligned} & \sqrt{N_B+1}-\sqrt{N_B}=\sqrt{N_B}\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{N_B}}-1\right)=\sqrt{N_B}\left(1+\frac{1}{2 N_B}-1\right)=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{N_B}} \\ & \therefore\left(\sqrt{N_B+1}-\sqrt{N_B}\right)^2=\frac{1}{2 N_B}\end{aligned}$

Could you please guide me on how to achieve this? Any suggestions, explanations, or code examples would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only look at the exponent

```
Asymptotic[ -MK NS (Sqrt[NB + 1] - Sqrt[NB])^2 , {NB, Infinity, 1}]
(*-((MK NS)/(4 NB))*)
```

Result confirms eq 12 `Exp[-((MK NS)/(4 NB))]/2`

**addendum**

For Mathematica versions < 12.1 try

```
Normal[Series[ -MK NS (Sqrt[NB + 1] - Sqrt[NB])^2 , {NB, Infinity,1}]]
```

instead.

Comment: I tried this: expression = -MK NS (Sqrt[NB + 1] - Sqrt[NB])^2,  limitApproximation = Asymptotic[expression, {NB, Infinity, 1}], simplifiedResult = FullSimplify[limitApproximation] but final result shows "Asymptotic(-MK (Sqrt[NB]-Sqrt[NB+1])^2 NS,{NB,\[Infinity],1})". Am I doing anything wrong here? Please guide.

Comment: What's your Mathematica version? Mine is v12.2 Windows

Comment: Mathematica Version 11.
It worked ! Thank you very much.

Comment: @SumitSagar You're welcome!